# Application gets crashed and displays a Error in Thread(Fatal Signal)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, thread-synchronization

In LogCat :

```
12-16 01:49:49.139: A/libc(790): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 806 (Thread-93)

12-16 01:49:49.169: A/libc(790): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 824 (Thread-112)
```

I wrote a code for creating Threads one by one when a button is clicked.It switches to multiple screens. 
when i tap on button multiple time my app is closing automatically,how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you writing native code (e.g., using the NDK)?

Comment: Thanks for your replay ,but am using libgdx.so calling static {
       System.loadLibrary("gdx");
  } in my activity

Comment: Add some code to see where your code goes wrong.